# How can I hand over an <image id> for jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the user clicks on a picture on my site. Now the jQuery should get the id of the clicked image and change the image to another image:

Here's my jquery:

```
function changeCircle() { 
    // div "holen" var object =
    // var object = document.getElementById("Kuchen");
    // var id = obj;
    // object.src="img/icon-check.png";
    // $("#GarantienFrage1").attr('src', "img/icon-check.png");
    $("id").attr('src', "img/icon-check.png");
    // $(this.id).attr('src', "img/icon-check.png");
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Kuchen">
    <img id="GarantienFrage2" class="maus_pointer" alt="AAA" src="img/icon-uncheck.png" style="height: auto; width: auto;" onclick="javascript:changeCircle();" />
</div>
```

How can I get the image to change when I click on it?

Comment: Instead of screenshots of code, [please provide actual code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

Comment: Java isn't JavaScript;  I removed that tag

Comment: Hmm. @yshavit, I'm curious who said anything about Java.

Comment: @Ionut the question was originally tagged with Java

Comment: You described a scenario but not a problem. What is the issue with the code you have right now? Please include those details in the question.

Comment: I don't think `$("id")` does what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you need to know who is `this`
in your case is not being the `<img>` tag
therefore, I've put a `target` param to your function

```js
function changeCircle(target) {
    console.log('this is: ' + this);
    console.log('BEFORE: ' + $(target).attr('src'));
    $(target).attr('src', 'img/icon-check.png');
    console.log('AFTER: ' + $(target).attr('src'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Kuchen">
    <img id="GarantienFrage2" class="maus_pointer" alt="AAA" src="img/icon-uncheck.png" style="height: auto; width: auto;" onclick="javascript:changeCircle(this);" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is not targeting the image, its targeting the first `<id>` element on your DOM.

Change this:

```
$("id").attr('src', "img/icon-check.png");
```

to this:

```
$("img.maus_pointer").attr("src", "img/icon-check.png");
```

This selects that `<img>` element who's class is `maus_pointer` and changed the value of its `src` attribute.

Also, make sure that your new image source is relatively accessible from the page's location as you're not using an absolute path to target the new image.